# Django Admin - Create an object and Create+Add a many other object (ForeignKey)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a 'Test'(:a.k.a exam) model that can contain an indeterminate number of questions.
I would like to be able to create these tests directly in the Admin part of Django.
How should I proceed?
Do I have to program the logic from scratch or Django has already thought about this case?

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField()
    answer_a = models.Boolean()
    solution_a = models.Boolean()
    ...

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class TestQuestion(models.Model):
    """connect many questions to a test"""
    test_fk = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    question_fk = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Django tutorial explains very well how to do this [Part 07](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial07/#adding-related-objects):

```
# Admin.py
class QuestionsOfTestInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = QuestionsOfTest
    extra = 3

class Test_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [QuestionsOfTestInline]
    
admin.site.register(Test, Test_Admin)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48363069/2) to the question [Django Admin - Create an object and Create+Add a many other object (ForeignKey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363069/django-admin-create-an-object-and-createadd-a-many-other-object-foreignkey) by the OP [Hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6914318/hugo) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>